# Tweaking FFMPEG Stream For Games For Open Source Projech

Tags: ffmpeg

Right now I am using FFMPEG to record and broadcast video games on a open source projected call Glitch: https://www.glitch.fun/

The problem is the streams are a little but choppy and pixelated. Here is an example video recording:

https://www.glitch.fun/streams/7e5b7557-d028-4d39-bc59-af3836f7e30d/watchrecording/c147ffda-d26d-4c5f-8be1-a8832ba03dfa

The FFMPEG command I am currently for getting the stream from a source and sending it to a recording file and to destinations is as follows:

```
ffmpeg [some_input_source] -vf scale=1920x1080 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 60 -b:v 4000k -maxrate 4000k -bufsize 4500k -vcodec libx264 -preset veryfast -keyint_min 24  -level 3.0 -s 1920:h=1080 -g  40 -x264opts no-scenecut -strict experimental -f [output_location]
```

What can I tweak in here to improve the quality of streaming for games?

Comment: 1) The veryfast encoding setting prioritizes low CPU usage at the cost of lower quality and higher bitrate. 2) Do you have the bitrate necessary to do 1080p@60fps? [Some sources](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1722171?hl=en#zippy=%2Cbitrate) recommend a bitrate of 12Mbps for this, while you're only using 4Mbps. 3) Are you dropping frames due to insufficient bandwidth?

Comment: @NickODell Thanks for the docs! I'm at 4mpbs when of CPU usage issues where too much CPU utilization is causing FFMPEG to crash. I'm already on a 8vcpu server and it starts to get expensive.

Comment: For H.264 1080p@60 fps you would need at least 10 Mbps for moderate motion and scene complexity. The CPU is most likely the bottleneck, you should go for GPU accelerated encoding.